# can not send jsp param when using HttpServletRequestWrapper?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I use Tomcat7. The structure of my project is :

- as1.jsp
- as2.jsp

The content of `web.xml` is :

```
  <filter-mapping>  
            <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>  
            <url-pattern>/as1.jsp</url-pattern>  
        </filter-mapping>
```

`filter1` used in HttpServletRequestWrapper :

```
...  
   RequestWrapper requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper(req);  
   requestWrapper.setParameter("params", new String[]{Item.getParams()});   
   chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);  
......
```

The content of `as1.jsp` is :

```
hi <br/>  
<jsp:include page="as2.jsp">  
        <jsp:param name="test" value="true" />            
</jsp:include>
```

The content of `as2.jsp` is :

```
as2 runed  
<br/>  
test:<%= request.getParameter("test") %>
```

When I deploy project I get this result :

```
hi  
as2 runed  
test:null
```

and when remove `HttpServletRequestWrapper` in `filter1` I get correct result:

```
hi  
as2 runed  
test:true
```

Please help me, how get `request.getParameter("test")` with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` in `filter1` ?
Thank you.

Comment: You use `requestWrapper.setParameter("params", new String[]{Item.getParams()}); ` and then `request.getParameter("test")`. Maybe try with `request.getParameter("params")`.

Comment: request.getParameter("params") return correct value  but jsp params return null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Filter RequestWrapper`  is overrding `.getParameter()` method  and not delegating to the original request.

Comment: please ,  Describe your proposed solution more ?

Comment: thank you . The problem was solved ​​with a modified   .getParameter()  method .

Comment: change the return value  to : return (val == null ? getRequest().getParameter(name) : val.toString());

Comment: in Wrapper?. Did my solution help?